# How to map custom enumerated integer ordinals with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, enumeration

I have an enum class named Status as follows

```
public enum Status {
    PENDING(0), SUCCESS(1), FAILED(-1);

    private int st;

    private Status(int st){
        this.st = st;
    }
}
```

and from other class I try to map this status enum

```
public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
```

when I run this code, I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ordinal value for enum class data.Status: -1
>     at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:93)
>     at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:124)
>     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
>     at

but I already have -1 in enum definition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could define your own `UserType` which defines how Hibernate should map those enums.

Note that the ordinal defines the index of the enum value and thus `FAILED` would have the ordinal 2. To map the enum using its properties your need a `UserType` implementation.

Some links:

- https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForPersistingAnEnumWithAVARCHARColumn
- http://javadata.blogspot.de/2011/07/hibernate-and-enum-handling.html (look at the "Paramterized Enumeration in Hibernate" section)

Comment: Use the below link for a good tutorial. It helped me to understand clearly.  http://www.gabiaxel.com/2011/01/better-enum-mapping-with-hibernate.html

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution where a string label is used instead of an int id, however it is simple to adapt.

```
public class User { 
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Type(type = "com.example.hibernate.LabeledEnumType")
    private Role role;
}


public enum Role implements LabeledEnum {
    ADMIN("admin"), USER("user"), ANONYMOUS("anon");

    private final String label;

    Role(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}


public interface LabeledEnum {
    String getLabel();
}


public final class LabeledEnumType implements DynamicParameterizedType, UserType {

    private Class<? extends Enum> enumClass;

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x == y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x == null ? 0 : x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String label = rs.getString(names[0]);
        if (rs.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        for (Enum value : returnedClass().getEnumConstants()) {
            if (value instanceof LabeledEnum) {
                LabeledEnum labeledEnum = (LabeledEnum) value;
                if (labeledEnum.getLabel().equals(label)) {
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown " + returnedClass().getSimpleName() + " label");
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            st.setString(index, ((LabeledEnum) value).getLabel());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Enum> returnedClass() {
        return enumClass;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{Types.VARCHAR};
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameterValues(Properties parameters) {
        ParameterType params = (ParameterType) parameters.get( PARAMETER_TYPE );
        enumClass = params.getReturnedClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the same. But it giving me column "user_role_type" is of type users.user_role but expression is of type bytea

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest following workaround. At first I was supprised it worked but it is really simple:
For enum:

```
    public enum Status {
    PENDING(0), SUCCESS(1), FAILED(-1);

    private int status;

    private Status(int status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public static Status parse(int id) {
        Status status = null; // Default
        for (Status item : Status.values()) {
            if (item.getStatus().equals(id)) {
                Status = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        return Status;
    }
}
```

class

```
class StatedObject{

    @Column("status")
    private int statusInt;

    public Status getStatus() {
        return Status.parse(statusInt);
    }

    public void setStatus(Status paymentStatus) {
        this.statusInt = paymentStatus.getStatus();
    }

    public String getStatusInt() {
        return statusInt;
    }

    public void setStatusInt(int statusInt) {
        this.statusInt = statusInt;
    }
}
```

if you are using hibernate in hibernate xml file it would be:

```
 <property name="statusInt "    column="status" type="java.lang.Integer" />
```

that is it